# How to Delete/Remove shape to make it transparent over another shape

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I'm Not a graphic designer as evident by this question. I have this shape in Illustrator & I need to export a transparent image (.png). In the middle of the black shape, there are 2 white shapes which have to be transparent. So, it's just the black that needs to be there, the white parts have to be transparent essentially. I have many shapes like this in a single artboard. I can do them one by one, if need be.
[image]

I cannot delete the white parts obviously because these are probably shapes too.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is hard to know how your shapes are constructed but one way is you can use Pathfinder to your benefit.

Click/ Drag to Select your shape

Go to Window> Pathfinder to open the Pathfinder Palette

Click either Divide or Merge

This will cut the shapes around each other

You can then selct and delete your unwanted shapes to reveal transparency behind them.

Comment: Thank you. It worked!